# Eclipse HTTP 404 not found error the requested resource tomcat server error

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

Wanted to run my html file on eclipse tomcat server when I clicked run on server
it gave me this error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trPfT.png)

Here is my html file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7Dm6.png)

I do not know why tomcat is not able to find my project file

Comment: It looks like you didn't request that file.

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Try right-clicking on the html file and choosing Run as> Run on server. Or change the url to http: // localhost: 8080 / NewFile3.html. The problem could be due to the fact that if you start the application starting from the project and not from the file, it looks for the index.html file, which is not present in your project. Alternatively, change the name of the html file to index.html. Hope this solves your problem.